# C++ - Conversion std::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

Brace yourselves! C++ newbie question incoming:

Can someone explain to me why this error occurs and how should I fix it?

```
std::vector<std::string> options = vectorOGROptions_.get()
```

I want to get `options` var as `std::vector<std::string>` but it seems my vectorOGROptions property returns a different type..

```
error: conversion from ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ requested
```

Comment: Assuming you're using C++03 and not C++11, do `std::vector<std::string> options(1, vectorOGROptions_.get());`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get()` function returns `string`, but you are trying to initialize vector with this string, that's not allowed.

You can use something like this

```
std::vector<std::string> options;
options.push_back(vectorOGROptions.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to a vector a string. You cannot do this. Use an initialiser list.

```
std::vector<std::string> options{vectorOGROptions_.get()};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that this `get()` function returns `const std::basic_string<char>`, which is nothing but `std::string`. Use vector's `push_back()` method:

```
std::vector<std::string> options;
options.push_back(vectorOGROptions_.get());
```